# How can I parse command line arguments?

Tags: perl, arguments, command-line-arguments

I want to parse a list of arguments in a perl script, for example i have this situation :

```
script.pl -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -p pass arg1 arg2 arg3
```

How can i do for parse the list of argument that aren't option in an array, and the option parameter in scalar value ?

Thanks.

Comment: In _Mastering Perl_, I talk about the 90+ Perl modules that let you do this in almost any way that you like. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, if they are the only things on the command line that aren't given as options, then they should still be in `@ARGV`. So just use `@ARGV`.

```
use Getopt::Long;

# save arguments following -h or --host in the scalar $host
# the '=s' means that an argument follows the option
# they can follow by a space or '=' ( --host=127.0.0.1 )
GetOptions( 'host=s' => \my $host 
          , 'user=s' => \my $user  # same for --user or -u
          , 'pass=s' => \my $pass  # same for --pass or -p
          );

# @ARGV: [ qw<arg1 arg2 arg3> ]
```

see [`Getopt::Long`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aLong)

Answer (score 14):

The arguments to your program are stored in `@ARGV`.

If you want to do any handling of switches at all, please use `Getopt::Long`, which is a standard Perl module.

Even if you think "Oh, I can just pick the stuff I want out of the list", please use `Getopt::Long`, because I guarantee you the time will come that you will add more switches, and you will wind up saying "Man, I wish I'd started using Getopt::Long from the beginning."

Please also see my blog post ["Use Getopt::Long even if you think you don't need it"](https://perlbuzz.com/2018/08/03/use-getoptlong-even-if-you-dont-think-you-need-to/).

Comment: That link is broken ( 404 )

Comment: Thanks, @Bogolt.  I dug it up out of the Wayback Machine, republished it, and updated the link.

Comment: Actually, better use argparse, that support positionnal arguments and have a way cleanner interface in my opinion