# Perl pass arguments into file from Bash

Tags: bash, perl, arguments

I have to run a function in a Perl file, and pass arguments into the function.

```
# program.pm

sub go
{
   # I need to use arguments here
   # print foo
   # print bar
}

my %functions = (
  go  => \&go
);

my $function = shift;

if (exists $functions{$function}) {
  $functions{$function}->();
} else {
  die "There is no function called $function available\n";
}
```

This needs to be run and passed through bash. I need to be able to specify the args randomly, something like this:

`$ perl program.pm go foo='bar' bar='fubar'`

I am very unfamiliar with Perl. I am Googling around and can't for the life of me figure out how to properly parse these. It seems like there's 4 different ways to do it and none seem to fit my use case.

I tried this to no avail as well.:

`$ perl program.pm -e 'go(foo=>"bar")'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972955/how-can-i-parse-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may "include" program.pm into your "one liner" using `require`.

shell/bash script

```
perl -e 'require "/path/program.pm" ; &go(1=>2)'
```

program.pm

```
sub go
{
   # sample subroutine

   # print subroutine parameters
   print "go-params: @_\n";
   # convert subroutine parameters into hash
   my %hash = @_;
   print "go-hash-1: $hash{1}\n"
}
# IMPORTANT: indicate proper module initialization
1;
```

Comment: Why do you `require` the program rather than just running it? And what does the `&` on the subroutine call achieve?

Comment: @DaveCross 1) Require is supposed to make **many subroutines** defined in program.pl available in the "one liner". 2) `&` is not necessary in this case to call `go` subroutine. It is my preferred style-guide. 3) You answer is "better & recommended style". My answer is "short code" and makes possible much more complicated uses of subroutned defined in program.pm

Comment: 1/ But if you just run the program, the subroutine will all be defined anyway. 2/ Using `&` is very rarely necessary to call subroutines. If that's your preferred method then you are writing code that is harder to read than it needs to be.

Comment: @DaveCross 1) Show your way of integrating subroutines from file and one liner (`-e` 2) "It is harder to read" - it is a matter of personal preferences and possibly "unfit" interpretation habits from other languages.  It makes code easier to read **for me**.

Comment: 1/ There's nothing to show. It just works. If you run a program from the command line then all of its subroutines are available to you. 2/ `&` isn't just a matter of personal preference. `&` can change the way that subroutines are called in obscure ways. Unless you understand the differences between `foo` and `&foo`, I would strongly recommend that you don't use the latter.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you have already accepted seems rather complicated. This is possible with just a couple of changes to your existing code.

```
sub go
{
   # I need to use arguments here
   # print foo
   # print bar
   print "In go\nArgs are: @_\n";
}

my %functions = (
  go  => \&go
);

my $function = shift;

if (exists $functions{$function}) {
  # Pass remaining command-line args to the called subroutine
  $functions{$function}->(@ARGV);
} else {
  die "There is no function called $function available\n";
}
```

I've put a `print()` call in `go()` (so I know it's being called) and I've passed `@ARGV` to the subroutine found in the dispatch table.

You can just call it like any other Perl program.

```
$ perl program.pm go foo=bar bar=fubar
In go
Args are: foo=bar bar=fubar

$ perl program.pm XX foo bar
There is no function called XX available
```

**Update:** In a comment, this requirement was added:

> But how do i split the values into a hash?

There are two answers to this. And which one you choose depends on what you're actually trying to do.

If you just want to take any "foo=bar" string and parse it into a key/value pair stored in a hash, then you can replace the `go()` subroutine with code like this:

```
use Data::Dumper;

sub go
{
   # I need to use arguments here
   # print foo
   # print bar

   my %args = map { split /=/ } @_;

   print "In go\nArgs are: " . Dumper(\%args) . "\n";
}
```

You then get this output:

```
$ perl program.pm go foo=bar bar=fubar
In go
Args are: $VAR1 = {
          'bar' => 'fubar',
          'foo' => 'bar'
        };
```

If you're actually trying to parse command line options, then you should use a command line option parser like [GetOpt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long).

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long 'GetOptionsFromArray';

sub go
{
   # I need to use arguments here
   # print foo
   # print bar

   my %args;

   GetOptionsFromArray(\@_, \%args, 'foo=s', 'bar=s');

   print "In go\nArgs are: " . Dumper(\%args) . "\n";
}
```

Note that for this to work, you'll need to pass proper Unix-style options that start with `--`.

```
$ perl program.pm go --foo=bar --bar=fubar
In go
Args are: $VAR1 = {
          'bar' => 'fubar',
          'foo' => 'bar'
        };
```

But this version is far more flexible in its input requirements:

```
$ perl program.pm go --f bar --b fubar
In go
Args are: $VAR1 = {
          'bar' => 'fubar',
          'foo' => 'bar'
        };
```

And it will tell you if you're using invalid option names.

```
$ perl program.pm go --fu=bar --baz=fubar
Unknown option: fu
Unknown option: baz
In go
Args are: $VAR1 = {};
```

Comment: But how do i split the values into a hash?

Comment: Oh. I apologise for not spotting a requirement that you didn't think to mention in your question :-)

Comment: Haha sorry! I do like your way better, if theres some easy eay to parse them.